# Parametrizing input using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, sql-injection

I want to parametrize my stored procedure's input to prevent sql injection. The problem is MY database has no application(It's just for school) & as there's no client language like C# etc, I have to do it with sql itself. i did this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[drop_tt]
@ss varchar(40)
as
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT *
FROM    tt
whERE   ss = @Ss', N'@ss varchar(40)', @ss
```

but when I execute this statement the tt table was droped :(
exec drop_tt 'www';drop table tt--'

anyone can help?

Comment: how sql injection is happening if you don't have any UI ?

Comment: I should do it myself. It's for my school. that's why no application. but I should write a statement myself as a user an try to inject some instruction like exec drop_tt 'www';drop table tt--'

Comment: exec drop_tt 'www';drop table tt--' - this isn't really injection, if run in a SQL window you have issued two commands in SSMS seperated by the semi-colon. Your stored procedure should never even gets the drop command to accidently execute - but SSMS will execute the second statement on its own. Get some debug going and you should be able to confirm that is the case.

Comment: Like Andrew says, exec drop_tt 'www'; drop table tt; are two separate commands.  It's the same if I wrote: exec drop_tt @ss='www'; select * from tt;

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** why are you altering sp? you just need to create a parametrized stored procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address
WHERE City = @City
GO
```

Just look at this very [simple tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/) , you don't need to alter your procedures.

**Edit:** my approach would be to get rid off the statement `EXEC sp_executesql` and naming that starts with `drop`. Just try to simplify your stored procedure execution statement in the body.

Comment: tnx for answering. but If I write this way. It will drop my table when I use the statement like above. I think I should convert the input to string that have no execution ability & that's why we parametrized it. but in this way "drop command" that I injected run anyway